# How to get the number of jbutton present on jframe

Tags: java, swing

I have this code by which I am trying to count/get the number of jbuttons present on jframe

I have 7 jbuttons and 2 jtext fields on jframe but Output is coming 1

```
Component c=this;
Container container = (Container) c;
int x = container.getComponentCount();
System.out.println(x);
```

Can I get some guidance

Comment: Probably you have only one `JPanel` inside the container - And that's what `getComponentCount()` is returning. You should get the `JPanel` and `getComponentCount()` on it.

Comment: Are you using a canvas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495769/how-to-get-all-elements-inside-a-jframe see this question may help in your case

Comment: I am using JFrame with JList and JTextArea with Jbutton and Jtext Field

Answer (score 2):

Get all the components in the JFrame(hint: use recursion as done [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GetAllComponentsinacontainer.htm)).

```
public static List<Component> getAllComponents(final Container c) {
    Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
    List<Component> compList = new ArrayList<Component>();
    for (Component comp : comps) {
      compList.add(comp);
      if (comp instanceof Container) {
        compList.addAll(getAllComponents((Container) comp));
      }
    }
    return compList;
  }
```

Then test for the components that are jbuttons.

```
int count =0;
for(Component c : getAllComponents(container)){
  if(c instanceof JButton) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your first line:

```
Component c = (your JFrame object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) to recursively search Containers for components.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd be better counting the components in the hierarchy rather than on a single component, for example:

```
public static int countSubComponentsOfType(Container container, Class<? extends Component> type){
    int count = 0;
    for(Component component : container.getComponents()){
        if(type.isInstance(component)) count++;
        if(component instanceof Container) 
            count += countSubComponentsOfType((Container)component, type);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Alternatively, if you genuinely want the components on a JFrame, use the following instead.

```
frame.getRootPane().getComponentCount();
```

This is because JFrame always just contains 1 child component, a JRootPane. Anything added to the JFrame is added to the rootpane.